# Putting create action for one model in show page of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039377/help-with-create-action-in-a-different-show-page) earlier and got part of the way to where I needed to be.

I have a simple app that has three tables. Users, Robots, and Recipients. Robots belong_to users and Recipients belong_to robots.

On the robot show page, I want to be able to create recipients for that robot right within the robot show page.

I have the following code in the robot show page which lists current recipients:

```
<table>

<% @robot.recipients.each do |recipient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><b><%=h recipient.chat_screen_name %></b> via <%=h recipient.protocol_name</td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_recipient_path(recipient) %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', recipient, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and now I have this in the Robot show view:

```
<% form_for(@recipient) do |f| %>
Enter the screen name<br>
<%= f.text_field :chat_screen_name %>
<p>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

and the robots controller has this added to it also:

```
@recipient = Recipient.new
  @recipients = Recipient.all
```

I now see the field I want to see, but it seems as though the recipient is still not being associated with the robot who's show page the user is on.  Moreover, when I have this code in, the redirect upon creation is going to the recipients index page, as opposed to the robot show page.

I have this code in the recipents controller in the create action:

```
      def create
    @recipient = Recipient.new(params[:recipient])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipient.save
        flash[:notice] = 'The new recipient was successfully added.'
        format.html { redirect_to (robot_path(@recipient.robot)) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @recipient, :status => :created, :location => @recipient }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @recipient.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'd really appreciate any additional help.  I know I'm close to the solution but not quite there....  :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@recipient = Recipient.new(params[:recipient])
```

This creates a new Recipient based on the submitted form, but there's nothing in the form designating the robot you want to use. Because there's no params[:recipient][:robot_id], there can't be a @recipient.robot.

Either try a nested resource and accessing the robot id from the url params, or try passing a hidden field containing the robot id and accessing it from the submitted form.

Key point here: params[:recipient] only contains what's passed from the form, and you aren't passing the robot id anywhere.

Comment: Jarrod, thanks for this explanation. I wasn't sure how to get the ID associated with it, and ultimately ended up going with a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested route and then in create: (this is a slightly different approach that the other answer)

```
@robot = Robot.find(params[:bug_id])
@recipient = Robot.recipients.new(params[:recipient])
```

This will automatically create `@recipient` with `robot_id` set correctly.